# Migrate workflow history list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow

I'm currently migrating a SharePoint 2010 website to another server, which contains a list workflow. The migration of the website and the workflow wasn't a problem at all, but I also want to migrate the data inside the workflow history list. It seems that there's no out-of-the-box solution. I have gone through a lot of posts and solutions, but they don't really fit my needs. The following two pictures are what I expect to see on the workflow site of a list element and what currently the situation is (it's a German SharePoint).

**Old Server**

[image]

**New Server**

[image]

Here's what I have tried so far:

1. SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard

   - This one has an option to export the workflow history list, but the author of the tool has said that it cannot Export data from the workflow history list due to some restrictions in the Content API.
2. Export/Import of the workflow history list as a template

   - I exported the workflow history list and checked the box that I want to include all the list data. On the new server I'm not able to see the template in the list creation dialog after uploading it to the appropriate library.
3. Copy and paste via the data sheet view

   - I exported the workflow history list of the old server to an Excel sheet and tried to copy them to the new list via the data sheet view. Here I'm getting an error saying that the cells are read-only. I have seen some Solutions using the SharePoint web service to manipulate the read-only property, but custom code is not a real solution in my Situation (in an exceptional situation a PowerShell script would work).

I have also seen solutions which changed the workflow deletion job scheduler, but this only stops cleaning the content database.

Are there any other ways to solve this problem I haven't come across yet?